# clear label without affecting size

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I am working on a hangman game in c# and I have to create multiple labels dynamically for each of the characters of the generated word.

This is the code I'm using :

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < game.word.Length; i++)
{
    char c = game.word[i];
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = c.ToString();
    label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
    label.AutoSize = true;
    label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    x += label.Width;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

This is how it shows :

[image]

However I want the label to be empty, so I did this :

```
// label.Text = c.ToString();
label.Text = "";
```

And it shows like this :

[image]

How can I clear the label without affecting its size ?

Comment: `label.MinimumSize = label.PreferredSize;` after all the other label properties are set.

Comment: I tried it but the same output

Comment: it works now thanks @Loathing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Loathing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904156/loathing)'s comment, I was able to solve it by setting `MinimumSize` to `PreferredSize` then clear the label but only after all the labels had been added.

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
for (...)
{
...
}
foreach(Control control in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
{
    if(control is Label)
    {
        control.MinimumSize = control.PreferredSize;
        control.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code I see that you have set the `AutoSize` property to **true** which is making the label to adapt its size with respect to the text inside it.

Set it to **false** and change the Height and Width to desired size. Now the size of label will not change even if you change the text to blank.

```
  label.AutoSize = false;
```

However, If you assign multiple characters in your label It will still remain to the set size and the other characters will be hidden unless the label is resized enough to make all the characters visible.

Set `AutoSize` property to **false** when you are sure that the content of the label will not exceed the length of the label.